# parseInt behaviour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I open terminal browser (Chrome for example).

I write this:

```
var y = "11000011010101011";
```

> "11000011010101011"

```
parseInt(y)
```

> 11000011010101012

I expected `11000011010101011` but it returns me `11000011010101012`.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: I guess your number is too big. Read that: http://bjola.ca/coding/largest-integer-in-javascript/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every number in Javascript is represented as a [double precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). JavaScript can accurately represent integers only up to 9007199254740991 (2^53 - 1). Once you get over that limit, you will loose precision.

Comment: Aka [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Answer (score 0):

Only `9007199254740991` is the safe integer in javascript.
This is case something like

```
9007199254740992 + 1 // 9007199254740992
9007199254740993 + 1 // 9007199254740992
9007199254740994 + 1 //9007199254740996
```

Please see the links for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html

Also see this one
[how addition of Number works on max limit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973864/how-addition-of-number-works-on-max-limit-numbers)
This is the dublicate questions see its original

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) page.

All number in Javascript are 64-bit floating point number, and integers are represented by the 53-bit mantisa. 
Because of that, you can't store a integer larger than 2^53 -1 and smaller than -2^53 +1 without losing precission (Javascript rounds your number in order to be able to store it).

Your number is larger than 2^53 -1. Even though a String can store it, in order to store it in a "Number" variable, it has to be rounded, losing the precision and returning you a slightly different number.